# latitudes and longitudes are two dimensional arrays in netcdf file?

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I'm trying to open, read, and plot cloud cover data from a netCDF file. The file opens and plots fine in the Panoply viewer, so the data looks to be OK. But I can't figure out for the life in me how to convert the latitudes and longitudes into a 1-D array each, they seem to be 2-D. Which makes NaN sense to me...

Reading the file and variables works fine:

```
fh = Dataset("/home/ubuntu/HIMA8_CC/Himawari8_AHI_FLDK_2020171_0140_00_CLOUD_MASK_EN.nc", mode='r')
lon = fh.variables['Longitude'][:]
lat = fh.variables['Latitude'][:]
cloud_mask = fh.variables['CloudMask'][:]
```

However, the dimensions of the latitude and longitude variable are 2D, I would have expected those to be 1D:

```
print(lon.shape)
print(lat.shape)
print(np.mean(lon))
print(cloud_mask.shape)
print(np.mean(lon))
print(np.mean(cloud_mask))
```

prints

```
(5500, 5500)
(5500, 5500)
91.97970824333167
(5500, 5500)
91.97970824333167
1.8154066433116118
```

the mean values look as expected. Can anyone with netCDF experience shed some light on what it is I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the file? You can possibly amend this using NCO, but you would need to upload the file first to see how

Comment: The file can be downloaded here https://noaa-himawari8.s3.amazonaws.com/AHI-L2-FLDK-Clouds/2020/06/19/0140/Himawari8_AHI_FLDK_2020171_0140_00_CLOUD_MASK_EN.nc What is NCO?

Comment: You will need to reshape your arrays to 1D. Each element of the 2D arrays represent one point in space. The [i,j] in lon and lat give you the longitude and latitude in cloud_mask. You would also want to use lon.mask to remove any masked data.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
import xarray as xr

fh = xr.open_dataset('/home/ubuntu/HIMA8_CC/Himawari8_AHI_FLDK_2020171_0140_00_CLOUD_MASK_EN.nc')

lon = fh['Longitude'].values.flatten()
lat = fh['Latitude'].values.flatten()
```